# Is there any difference between a weak learner and a weak classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, xgboost, supervised-learning, ensemble-modeling

While reading about decision tree ensembles [Gradient Boosting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.06951), [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) etc.

I have found the following two concepts **weak learner** and **weak classifier**.

Are they the same?

If there is any difference what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A weak learner can be either a classification or a regression algorithm:

> Boosting (Schapire and Freund 2012) is a greedy algorithm for fitting adaptive basis-function models of the form in Equation 16.3, where the $\phi_m$ are generated by an algorithm called a weak learner or a base learner. The algorithm works by applying the weak learner sequentially to weighted versions of the data, where more weight is given to examples that were misclassified by earlier rounds.
>   **This weak learner can be any classification or regression algorithm, but it is common to use a CART model.**

*Source: "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective"; Murphy; 2012*

So a weak classifier is simply a weak learner which is a classifier.

Comment: okey! perfect! Thanks for the citation :)